# How to get last index in a map with some null items

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist, hashmap

I got a `Map(int,List<String>)` and some of the lists inside are null for example:

`{1 = [example1, 2000, May 22, 2020] , 2 = [example2, 120, May 30, 2020] ,  4 = [example3, 120, May 30, 2020]}`

so in my example the list in index 3 is null.

so I want do get the highest index in the map in my example it'll be 4.

Comment: `Map(int,List<String>)` or `Map<Integer,List<String>>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `keySet()` to get all key and use `Collections.max` to get max index

```
int maxSet = Collections.max(map.keySet());
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Java 8 stream**.

You can stream over the `keyset` of the map and call the max operation on that stream. Check the snippet below:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class HighestValueInMap {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Integer, List<String>> exampleMap = new HashMap<>();
        exampleMap.put(1, Arrays.asList("example1", "2000", "May 22", "2020"));
        exampleMap.put(2, Arrays.asList("example2", "120", "May 30", "2020"));
        exampleMap.put(4, Arrays.asList("example3", "120", "May 30", "2020"));
        System.out.println("exampleMap is = " + exampleMap);
        Integer max = exampleMap.keySet().stream().mapToInt(v -> v).max().getAsInt();
        System.out.println("The max value present in the map is = " + max);
    }
}
```